# When is memory allocated by malloc garbage collected?

Tags: malloc, julia

I am guessing (hoping) the answer is never.
That such memory must be explicitly freed.

For example if if I wrote:

```
julia> x = Libc.malloc(1_000_000)
Ptr{Void} @0x0000000002f6bd80

julia> x = nothing
```

have I just leaked ~1MB of memory?

However I am not 100% certain this is true,
because the docs don't mention it at all.

> `help?> Libc.malloc(3)`
>          `malloc(size::Integer) -> Ptr{Void}`
>
> Call malloc from the C standard library.

Comment: Almost sounds as if you _aspire_ to leak 1MB of memory there :p

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you are correct.

Julia is designed to seamlessly interoperate with C on a low level, so when you use the C wrapper libraries, you you get C semantics and no garbage collection.

The docs for Libc.malloc is not written to teach C, but could be improved to mention Libc.free, in case anyone gets confused.

Answer (score 1):

Yet one more answer

Yes you leaked 1MB of memory. But there's a mechanism that implements ownership transfer

```
struct MyStruct
    ...
end

n = 10
x = Base.Libc.malloc(n * sizeof(MyStruct)) # returns Ptr{Nothing}
xtyped = convert(Ptr{MyStruct}, x) # something like reinterpret cast

vector = unsafe_wrap(Array, xtyped, n; own = true) # returns Vector{MyStruct}
```

N.B. The last line transfers ownership of memory to Julia, hence, from this moment it's better to avoid using of `x` and `xtyped` as they can point to already freed memory.

Such low-level kung fu can prove helpful while dealing with binary files especially with function `unsafe_read`.

Alternatively, as it was mentioned you can use `Base.Libc.free(x)` to manually free up memory.

P.S. However it is often better to rely on built-in memory management. By default immutable structs are tried to be allocated on stack, which improves performance.